Load snowflake conda packages in DBT python model
I'm trying to import some Snowflake conda channel packages in a python model inside DBT. But I run into the folowing error when I run dbt build on my model:

Cannot create a Python function with the specified packages. Please check your packages specification and try again.

But when I compile the same code in DBT Cloud IDE and run it in Snowsight it works just fine (i have to select the packages I want to import from the "anaconda packages" tab in the "Packages" section inside snowsight).
Here is my model code :
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import faiss
import numpy as np

def model(dbt, session): 

    dbt.config(
        packages = [
            'faiss-cpu',
            'numpy', 
            'pandas',
            'scikit-learn',
        ]
    )

    
    scrapped_products = dbt.ref('mart_dwh__d_products').to_pandas()
    
    scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8')
    
    scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.upper()
    
    scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', ' ', regex=True)
    
    scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.replace(' +', ' ', regex=True)

    
    customer_products = dbt.ref('seed__mil_products_catalog').to_pandas()
    
    customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8')
    
    customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.upper()
    
    customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', ' ', regex=True)
    
    customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'] = customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME'].str.replace(' +', ' ', regex=True)

    
    tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(1, 3))
    
    
    scrapped_product_vectors = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(scrapped_products['PRODUCT_NAME']).toarray()
    
    customer_product_vectors = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(customer_products['PRODUCT_NAME']).toarray()

    
    d = scrapped_product_vectors.shape[1]
    
    
    index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(d)
    
    index.add(np.array(scrapped_product_vectors, dtype=np.float32))

    
    distances, indices = index.search(np.array(customer_product_vectors, dtype=np.float32), 1)  

    
    match_result = []
    
    for i, (scrapped_idx, customer_idx) in enumerate(zip(indices, distances)):
        match_result.append({
            'CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID': customer_products.iloc[i]['PRODUCT_ID'],  # ID of the current customer product
            'SCRAPPED_PRODUCT_ID': scrapped_products.iloc[scrapped_idx[0]]['ID'],  # Matched scrapped product ID
            'SIMILARITY_RATIO': 1 / (1 + customer_idx[0]),  # Convert Euclidean distance to a similarity score
            'PROCESSED_AT': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")  # Timestamp of processing
        })

    final_df = pd.DataFrame(match_result)

    session.use_database(dbt.this.database)
    session.use_schema(dbt.this.schema)
    return_df = session.create_dataframe(final_df)

    return return_df

How I make it work in snowsight

I'd like to know what i'm missing. I tried various way but none seems to work. I always get the same error. I also tried to add my packages to a stage and reference them in my code but ultimatly run into the same error.

EDIT
DBT Generated proc python version :

Error when trying to use python 3.8 in snowsight :

Is there a way to set a custom python version in dbt ?

Are you using the same version of Python in both dbt and Snowsight Worksheet (3.11)? Second, have you tried specifying a concrete version of package (similar to Snowsight)? dbt.config(         packages = [ "scikit-learn==1.5.1"]     )

@LukaszSzozda  you may be right. When looking into the generated sql procedure, I noticed that the runtime version of python used is "3.8" (I edit my post to add a screenshot of it). And I get an error about sklearn version while setting python version to 3.8 in snowsight for my code (added a sc too). But I don't have any clue how to make dbt use a particular version of python.

The discrepancy was caused by Python version used in dbt and Snowsight Worksheet. One important note: Python 3.8 Runtime will soon be deprecated - Snowflake Deprecating and decommissioning runtimes (end of support)

To set a custom python version i just had to specify it in my config block as following :

and it works fine

